# find or generate all octal numbers from 0 to 8^10 that digit sum is equal to x

Tags: python, python-3.x

So given an input of 0o11110000000 base 8 ('0o' is ignored) i have to generate and count how many possible numbers that when the individual numbers are added they are the same. for example

- 0o1111000000 :  1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 4
- 0o0000001111 :  0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4
- 0o0000000201 :  0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 0 + 1 = 3

so for an input of 0o0000000001 i should get an answer of 10

```
0000000001
0000000010
0000000100
0000001000
0000010000
0000100000
0001000000
0010000000
0100000000
1000000000
```

My method is a very very brute force method in which i have to check every possible number from 0 to 7777 7777 77 base8. It uses the decimal represtation of the octal numbers and i use a recursive function to retrieve the octal sum of a number

How can i improve this to be a lot more faster. If possible no python modules as i doubt the machine running the program is unable to import a lot of stuff

```
def sum_of_octal_digits( n ):
    if n == 0 :
        return 0
    else:
        return int(n) % 8 + sum_of_octal_digits( int(n / 8) )


octInput = input("Enter hex: ")
int_octInput  = int(octInput , 16)
total = sum_of_octal_digits(int_octInput )


allcombinations  = list()
for i in range(pow(8,len(e[2:]))):
    if sum_of_octal_digits(i) == total :
        allcombinations.append(i)
    
    
print(len(allcombinations))
```

Comment: If it's base 8, shouldn't the range be `[0, 7 777 777 777]`?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur yes you are right, i fixed that mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're counting the number of sequences of {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} of length n that sum to t. Call that value `S[n, t]`.

There's a recurrence relation that `S[n, t]` satisfies:

```
S[0, 0] = 1
S[0, t] = 0 (t != 0)
S[n+1, t] = sum(S[n, t-d] for d=0...min(t, 7))
```

Once you have the recurrence relation, solving the problem using dynamic programming is straightforward (either by using memoization, or using a bottom-up table approach).

The program should run in O(nt) time and use O(nt) space.

Comment: Im having trouble understanding half of what you have said. Is the code you have posted python? im not aware of that style of syntax

Comment: That isn't "code", that's just a recurrence relation

Comment: The concept is way too advance for me... Can you please simplify it for me into a step-by- step format that is easier for me to digest.

Comment: @DrakeJest a recurrence relation can be thought of as a mathematical representation of a recursive function. It should be easy to express it in python: `def S(n, t): if n==t==0: return 1; if n==0: return 0; return sum(S(n-1, t-d) for d in range(min(t, 7)+1))` for example. Then you just need to optimize it, for example, by adding a memoization decorator.

Comment: @PaulHankin I tried it with a small number first `S(pow(8,4), 1)` and im getting an error on `return sum(S(n-1, t-d) for d in range(min(t, 7)+1))` .  I tried to     `sum = 0; for d in range(min(t,7)+1):  sum += Search(n-1, t-d); return sum;` it seems to be taking a while for such few numbers.

Comment: n is the number of digits and not the number itself, so 10 for example rather than pow(8, 10). Like all dynamic programming exercises, the recursive function itself is not likely to be fast, and you have to memoize or rewrite the function in a bottom-up table-based way.

Comment: For n=10 I guess even the recursive version is fast enough though.

Comment: I get the impression that you're solving problems that require dynamic programming but you aren't yet familiar with the subject. There's a lot of resources out there on dynamic programming that can help you.

Comment: I got it working ! and yes i also feel like im biting more than i can chew here, but this is a great starting point. so far on small numbers its working , i cant check the full 10 digits takes to long.